# Java double char array testing error

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

[image](Click on the screenshot to to see a larger version.)

My getActiveState() method and getColumn(x, y) method on line 251 have previously been tested and are fully working so I don't understand why I am getting an error about it now. Can anyone explain?

Comment: Are you expecting people to read code from a screen shot? Or is there something else in this picture that I am missing?

Comment: ya, if you click on it will zoom in. You can also click "ctrl + " on your keyboard to zoom in.

Comment: If you really want help you would at least copy paste the relevant code into the question. The harder you make people have to work to help you, the less likely they are.

Comment: I wanted to show them all the information they needed. My picture has all the relevent code and more. maybe instead of complaining about my question try reading the question next time?

Comment: @628496 Don't you know what exception is or what nullpointerexception is? What is your question about?

Comment: I know what a nullPointerException is but I don't understand how I am getting it. I definitely instantiated the this.region variable and both of the methods i invoke on line 251 have been tested to work so I don't understand why i am getting an error.

Comment: @628496 You can simply debug your code and see when the method `getColumn(x,y)` returns `null`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think the NullPointerException occurs in following code line

Line 251

```
this.region.getColumn(x, y) // is null for some kind of columns ...
```